# Assign enter key to close button in Magnific Popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

I have a functioning popup form that I use with Magnific Popup Lightbox.  Inside I have a custom close button that handles the collected information when clicked.  I would like the user to be able to press enter (at any time, not just after the final text box) and have the close button activated.  My code is as follows:

```
$.magnificPopup.open({
    items: {
       src: 'nameselect.html',
       type: 'ajax'
    },
    closeOnContentClick : false, 
    closeOnBgClick :true,
    showCloseBtn: false,
    enableEscapeKey : false,
    callbacks: {
        open: function(){
            $.magnificPopup.instance.wrap[0].addEventListener('focus', function (e) {kNameSearch(e,focusText)});
            $(document).keypress(function(e){
                if (e.which == 13){
                    $("#cbutton").click();
                }
            });
        },
        afterClose: function(){
            document.getElementById("SearchName").blur();
        }
    }
});
```

But the `$(document).keypress(function(){})` lines don't seem to be working.  I have also tried inserting the code in the function called by the listener above it, with no success.  Any suggestions greatly welcomed.

Comment: replace $("#cbutton").click(); with $.magnificPopup.close();

Comment: Thanks, but my objective isn't to just close the popup.  I have a custom close button that assigns the data collected in the form to various variables.  I lose that if I just close the popup, because the form data isn't kept upon closure (my custom close button also calls `$.magnificPopup.close();`, btw).

Comment: can you make a fiddle of it?

Comment: AHHHH!  But your suggestion did help me solve it!  Instead of calling for the button to be clicked, I just had the key press call the button function directly.  THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to directly call the button function, not to try to "click" the button.  So this:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e){
   if (e.which == 13){
      $("#cbutton").click();
   }
});
```

was changed to this:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e){
   if (e.which == 13){
      closeButton();
   }
});
```

Given that the button was identified in the HTML as:

```
<input id="cbutton" onclick="closeButton()" type="button" value="Close" />
```